# Can I enter formula in the column for MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, database, formula

I wonder if the above can operate the column like the excel.

eg. same row. column 1 : A, column 2 : b, column 3 : A + b.

Comment: Please expand a little on what you want to do and in what context.

Comment: Hi Pekka, I need this option to automate the data (number) in column 3 so that I dont need to do the calculation separately. Data in column 3 will be use for analysis later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't look like MySQL supports computed columns as per SQL Server.

You could use a [View](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-view.html) with these calculated columns in or (if you want the value of the calculation to be persisted so you can search against it using an index) add a column and keep it up-to-date with triggers

Comment: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/databases/introduction-to-mysql-views/ voted this answer after read the link. It make sense and flexible.

Answer (score 5):

You can't have columns that *automatically* contain some neighbouring cell's value or do some calculations with it.

However, in a mySQL query, you can do all the things Excel can, and much much more.

For example, to get the sum of two `int` fields:

```
SELECT column_a, column_b, (column_a + column_b) as total FROM tablename
```

However, looking at your other questions, I'm not sure whether mySQL is really what you are looking for. It sounds to me like you need an application just like Excel.

Comment: :) guess I just have to keep trying. I dont think there is a application for 'like excel' + database. What do you think?

Comment: @King not entirely, that's true. But mySQL plus a graphical frontend like HeidiSQL (www.heidisql.com) can come close. Looking a second time at your other questions, and seeing that you *do* come from Excel, you may be on the right way after all!

Answer (score 3):

you can create a view of the table like you mention

like :

```
create view myview as select a,b,(a+b) as c from table
```

Answer (score 2):

mysql is a database and not a spreadsheet so no you can't, and you probably shouldn't be anyway.

I suppose the point is that a spread sheet holds AND displays the data - mysql holds the data then you use php to show the data (or similar).

When you retrieve from the database you can do:

```
SELECT (A+B) AS c FROM table
```

or when you put into the database you can do the maths.

Comment: If that was really true there would be no computed columns.

Answer (score 0):

I come from an Excel background myself and found that to be one of the challenges of moving over to databases, but I realize now that data is rarely presented as-is from a table.  Chances are you will be using a view because you or your end users will want to see it laid out a certain way.

Pretty much any time you think you want a calculated field, chances are you would do well to create a view that performs the calculation.  it also keeps the load off of any application you might be developing to use the info, because the calculations are done server-side.

Answer (score -1):

1. If you need the function of Excel but need it to store larger data sets using MySQL is fine.  However, to get the calculated columns you need to use an interface and Microsoft makes one called Access.  You can use Access to interact with your database and build queries to return your answers the way you want them.

This would keep you from having to build a web interface to your MySQL database to accomplish the same thing.